# Tabs position issue with Ext.tab.Panel

Tags: extjs

In ExtJs 4.2, I am using Ext.tab.Panel.

The issue I am facing is, tabs position is coming as center. What is property to set my tabs to right align?

Comment: It would be nice to see your code sample!

Comment: Hi there. As per your most recent question, requesting people not to downvote is not recommended here, since it clutters a question with noise and likely encourages more downvotes anyway. If people wish to downvote, they can and they will. The best solution is to _demonstrate_ effort in your question, mainly by posting the code you have already, or better yet, an internet-reachable example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The tab bar of `Ext.tab.Panel` is instance of `Ext.tab.Bar` class

`Ext.tab.Panel` have `tabBar` config where you can define extra configuration for tab panel's tab bar.

There you can set alignment of tabs to center by:

```
    tabBar: {
        layout: { pack: 'center' }
    },
```

See fiddle: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/1sc

Comment: It is not working for me...

Comment: yes now working but are other properties

Comment: This is simplest way how to align tabs in tab bar which I know. Where is your problem? Can you show your code?

Comment: In your example if I set pack to 'right' then also it is not set to right...can you tell me other pack values

Comment: As you can see in the documentation http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.layout.container.Box-cfg-pack acceptable `pack` configuration values are `start`, `center`, `end`

Comment: thanks..end is correct one